# In Excel how to count filled cells with text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

how can I count cells which has certain text [no matter value] and not empty.
If I use functions such as count or count-if it asks for value range what I need is any text.
Is there a code to write in macro to solve this out?.

in example to count the selected area cells 139-119=20.
where I need to select multiple places and count.

[image]

Comment: How about `=istext(a:a)`? Where  `a:a` is the column containing the text.  I haven't checked this but it would be a good place to start

Comment: OK this returns True there is text, I prefer to count them. should be a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use COUNTA function to count non blank cells in range as shown in the snapshot.
Please see this reference. [Use COUNTA to count nonblank cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-COUNTA-to-count-nonblank-cells-182926c1-50ce-4e66-8018-6ecf4ccc3dbf)

[image: snapshot showing results of COUNTA Function]